# SwiftUI @ObservedObject updating view's state from the back-stack?

Tags: swiftui, state, combine

I'm implementing a Timer, to show an Alert after 10 seconds, using Combine's Publisher and @ObservedObject, @StateObject or @State to manage states in a screen A. The problem is when I navigate to screen B through a NavigationLink the Alert still show up.

Is there a way to process the state changes of a view only when it's on top?

```
struct NavigationView: View {

    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .default)
         .autoconnect()
         .receive(on: DispatchQueue .main)
         .scan(0) { counter, _ in
             counter + 1
         }
     @State private var counter = "Seconds"
     @State private var alert: AlertConfiguration?


     var body: some View {

         ZStack {
             HStack(alignment: .top) {
                 Text(counterText)
                 Spacer()
             }
        
             NavigationLink(
                 destination: destinationView
             ) {
                 Button(Strings.globalDetails1) {
                     navigationAction()
                }
            }
         }
         .onReceive(timer) { count in
             if count == 10 {
                 makeAlert()
             }
             setSeconds(with: count)
         }
         .setAlert(with: $alert) // This is just a custom ViewModifier to add an Alert to a view
     }

     private func makeAlert() {
         alert = AlertConfiguration()
     }

     private func setSeconds(with count: Int) {
         counter = "seconds_counter".pluralLocalization(count: count)
     }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you drop the it's subscription when you move away from the screen and subscribe it back again when to come to this screen?

Comment: Then you'll have to restart the Timer, in this case, when resubscribing. I'd like the behavior where the result is kept in cache until I move back to screen A.

Comment: How about you pause the timer, when you move away and when you come back you start the timer? What exactly you want to achieve here?

Comment: Can you provide some sample code?

Comment: @SaketKumar Back in UIKit, when subscribing to RxSwift's Observable if I navigate to screen B then back to screen A after 10 seconds, I find the Alert shown (this is the desired behavior). Now with this implementation, after the 10 seconds pass the Alert shows up even when I'm still in screen A (undesired behavior).

Comment: So pretty much, you want the alert only shown on page A when you come back to page A from other page after the 10 second window. If you are in page A only you don't want it to be shown.

in that case, why don't you just associate a condition, say a observable property "path" which monitors where you are at present, and plug this with timer logic?

Comment: No if I stay in screen A let the Alert be shown normally but if I move to screen B I don't want it to be shown there (as it shouldn't).

Answer (score 0):

You could add a variable that you set true if your View is in foreground and will be set false if you switch to a different View. Then you only increase the timer if said variable is true

```
.onReceive(timer) {
    if count == 10 {
        makeAlert()
    }
    if (timerIsRunning) {
        count += 1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So basically the solution is to have a publisher that supports the lifecycle of the screen (onAppear & onDisappear).

This Answer helped: [SwiftUI Navigation Stack pops back on ObservableObject update](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/665369?answerId=672857022#672857022)